# Transition between different points of views (SCNCameras) in SceneView

Tags: ios8, scenekit

I've built a basic scene for SceneKit, including several `SCNNode`s with geometries, `SCNLight`s, and an `SCNCamera`. I would now like to add functionality whereby the point of view shifts between different camera positions when the user taps on the screen.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I include several `SCNCamera`s in the scene and switch `sceneView.pointOfView` between them? Or should I rather update the position (and orientation) of a single camera. Also, how can I specify the transition path from moving from the old to the new camera position, i.e. use animation for the transition.

Answer (score 3):

changing the `pointOfView` of the view is the easiest way. But if you want to control the path you will have to move the camera yourself. You can do that with `SCNAction` or by using CoreAnimation explicit or implicit animations.

Comment: Is there any way to change `pointOfView` with some kind of animation?

Comment: yes. Simply change the point of view in a transaction: `[SCNTransaction begin] [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:1] ... [SCNTransaction commit]`